# JSF 1.2 Life Cycle understanding: Executing the ValueChangeListener #2

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

I am using JSF v1.2 for my application. This is a sort-of-similar question to this thread (answered by BalusC) which I marked as answered some days back.

[JSF 1.2 Life Cycle understanding: Executing the ValueChangeListener method in InvokeApplication phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261687/jsf-1-2-life-cycle-understanding-executing-the-valuechangelistener-method-in-in)

No `dataTable` this time, only a form with a `dropdown` and a `panelgrid` containing some `outputText`. Based on the `dropdown` value selected by the user, some `outputText` fields present inside the `panelGrid` have to be populated.

Below is the code for the drop-down:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="drpDownLoans" value="#{loanBean.loanId }" valueChangeListener="#{loanBean.getLoanDetails }"  onchange="submit()">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select--" itemValue="0"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{loanBean.availableLoans }"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

On changing the drop-down value; I want to populate some `outputText` from the DB, below is the code:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel id="lblLoanId" value="Loan Id"></h:outputLabel>
        <h:outputText id="txtLoanId" value="#{loanBean.loanId }"></h:outputText>
        <h:outputLabel id="lblROI" value="Rate of Interest (% pa)"></h:outputLabel>
        <h:outputText id="txtROI" value="#{loanBean.rateOfInterest }"></h:outputText>
        <h:outputLabel id="lblNOI" value="No. of Installments (months))"></h:outputLabel>
        <h:outputText id="txtNOI" value="#{loanBean.noOfInstallments }"></h:outputText>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

Below is the code executed at the LoanBean.java:

```
public void getLoanDetails(ValueChangeEvent event){
    Integer value = (Integer)event.getNewValue();
    DataService service = new DataService();
    LoanBean loanBean = service.getLoanDetails(value);
    this.setLoanId(loanBean.getLoanId());
    this.setRateOfInterest(loanBean.getRateOfInterest());
    this.setNoOfInstallments(loanBean.getNoOfInstallments());
}
```

The code is working perfectly but don't know WHY :(

**My understanding: Default values for Integer i.e. 0 and String i.e. null should be displayed**

**WHY**

Both the `dropdown` and the `outputText` are present in the `form` element. When the form is submitted on drop-down value change, then the values of the fields present in the `panelGrid` are set to default i.e. for `integer`, the component#submittedValue will be `0` and for `String` it will be `null`. Since I dont have any Converter/Validator, the component#Value will also be `0` for `integer` and `null` for `String`. Then `ValueChangeEvent` will be executed and all the values are set to the `panelGrid` contents based on the values fetched from the DB. Then in phase 4, all these values set in phase 3 by the db hit should be reset to their default values based on the component#value which is set after the Convertor/Validator hence it should be `0` for `integer` and `null` for `String`. Then why are the values getting populated correctly rather than default values?

Yet again stuck conceptually on the life cycle events :( Please pin-ponit what I am missing in my mis-understanding.

Comment: as far as i understand your question is not about life cycles. you want to populate h:panel accordingly the selected item from SelectOneMenu. am i rigth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR: The fields are read-only**

Whilst your `panelGrid` binds to `loanBean` which is mutable, the `panelGrid` is only using output components (subclasses of `javax.faces.component.UIOutput`) which are by definition read only.  These do not have the methods which process request values (namely `UIInput.setSubmittedValue`, `UIInput.getSubmittedValue` and `UIInput.setValue`). In fact, when your form is submitted, the request includes no decoded values from the `OutputText` components.

For this reason, you do not need to play tricks during your `ValueChangeListener` process - it is safe to update the model values without worrying the the Apply Model Value phase will overwrite.

---

UIInput Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html

Debugging phases: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jsf2/section7.html